# Make a lightning component fit to screen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction

I have a custom lightning component. The lightning component is overridden in Contact Tab. Also, it appears as a popup in a Quick Action.

What I want is the Component to appear fit-to-screen both from the Tab as well as in the quick action popup dynamically. Is there any quick way to achieve this?

Comment: just a though, can you use the design component and create an attribute to check if it being rendered on the tab/ quick action? Configure your component's design bundle to work with a width matching the quick action and configure the design element to make the width different for a tab. http://blog.sujeshram.com/2016/12/identify-lightning-component-added-from-app-builder.html

Comment: I think quick actions are bound by an outer CSS you cannot override so that's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning Components are meant to be Modular, meaning that, whatever CSS rules you apply in your component, will remain scoped to that particualr component.

I have noticed however that loading a Styling Sheet from a static resource can modify the styling of its surrunding components if properly scoped, however, this is not considered a best pracitice, and will never be supported by Salesforce.

In Short, there is No quick-easy way to do this.